# SWIFT: Reading file: NSData successful, String fails. Why?

Tags: swift, file, io, bundle

I'm trying to read large data from file. It is a text file. The following line is successful, data is read into memory:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions(), error: &error)
```

This line return an error:

```
if let data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

But why? File is there, only Function is different. And I like to use second one, because I want to split all rows into separate strings in an array:

```
var array = data.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Any hint what to do?

Additional information: There are german umlauts, so code is larger than 127. But the file was saved as UTF-8. How could I load/use non ascii text?

Comment: what encoding is the file?

Comment: I used Textedit to save it. It's a text file with german words. How can I find out which encoding is used?

Comment: When you save the file TextEdit asks for an encoding.

Comment: When I create a new file, convert it to plain text and save it, I could sleect "Unicode UTF-8". That I used.

Comment: I used your String method to open a text file with umlauts and it worked. (I did save the file the same way you did in TextEdit.) You should print the error variable to see what happens in your case.

Comment: I tried to create a text file from scratch. I used TextEdit saved the fle as umlaut.txt, draged and dropped it into my bundle, but now path   >>> if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("umlaut", ofType: "txt") { <<<
    couldn't find it! Do I need to update special Caches? Is there a special place for the bundle files??? I even restarted XCode. Same result. New files were not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out every option and found the solution I didn't expect:

```
NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding
```

This setting accepts also german umlauts!